# Zend Framework Error Notice

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm trying to run this code.. But I get an error saying..

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp\www\address\application\views\scripts\index\index.phtml on line 64
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  374544  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0866  4624240 Zend_Application->run( )    ..\index.php:26
3   0.0866  4624240 Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run( )      ..\Application.php:366
4   0.0867  4624416 Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch( )  ..\Bootstrap.php:97
5   0.0984  5320368 Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch( )    ..\Front.php:954
6   0.1136  5637296 Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch( ) ..\Standard.php:295
7   0.1154  5674032 Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker->notifyPostDispatch( )  ..\Action.php:527
8   0.1154  5674792 Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->postDispatch( ) ..\HelperBroker.php:277
9   0.1155  5674792 Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->render( )   ..\ViewRenderer.php:960
10  0.1166  5675008 Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->renderScript( ) ..\ViewRenderer.php:921
11  0.1166  5675008 Zend_View_Abstract->render( )   ..\ViewRenderer.php:900
12  0.1168  5716176 Zend_View->_run( )  ..\Abstract.php:888
13  0.1171  5724528 include(   'C:\wamp\www\address\application\views\scripts\index\index.phtml' )  ..\View.php:108
```

This is my code...

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['search']))
{

$db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(array(
'host'     => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'dbname'   => 'addressdb'
));

$db->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);
$result = $db->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM user WHERE u_name = ?', $_POST['search']);

echo $result[0]->add1;


echo'<br><br><table width="200px" >';
echo'<tr ><th class="search">Name</th><td class="search">:</td><td class="search">'. $_POST['name'].'</td></tr>';
echo'<tr ><th class="search">Address1</th><td class="search">:</td><td class="search">'.$result[0]->add1.'</td></tr>';
echo'<tr ><th class="search">Address2</th><td class="search">:</td><td class="search">how</td></tr>';
echo'<tr ><th class="search">Address3</th><td class="search">:</td><td class="search">are</td></tr>';
echo'<tr ><th class="search">Telephone</th><td class="search">:</td><td class="search">you..</td></tr></table>';


}
?>
```

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong???

Comment: `echo $result[0]->add1;` to `echo $result->add1;`

Comment: Are you sure there is any result in your query? If not then you cannot access `$result[0]`

Comment: Sorry I'm really new to Zend.. What do you mean by "any result in your query?"

Comment: All I want to do is to retrieve a record from the DB according to a text box input. Do you have any other suggestions??

Comment: Always try to help your self first , `debug` your code. In above case you can check your return result by `var_dum($result)`. And then try to retrieve the value based on output.

Answer (score 0):

try doing:

```
$result = $db->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM user WHERE u_name = ?', $_POST['search']);

$countResult = count($result);
if($countResult > 0 ) {
  echo $result->add1;
}
else {
   ..you dont have any records, show some proper message
}
```

If you are fetching a single row, then you could do:

```
$result = $db->fetchRow('SELECT * FROM user WHERE u_name = ?', $_POST['search']);
$countResult = count($result);
if($countResult > 0 ) {
   echo $result->add1;
}
else {
   ..you dont have any records, show some proper message
}
```

Comment: Thanx.. But When I try your code, it goes inside the else part.

Comment: And show this error: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\address\application\views\scripts\index\index.phtml on line 89

Comment: that would mean you dont not have results for sql query, try placing hte html content part( as in your question) inside if condition, and in else show some message or something thats appropriate